How to run while read loop with concurrent connections?
I have a file containing list of servers:
server1.me.com
server2.me.com
server3.me.com

And this is my bash file:
#!/usr/bin/bash

while read -r line
do
    ssh -np2222 -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$line" \
    'mkdir -pv /root/newimages/'
    rsync -Ptrave 'ssh -p2222' /root/*.tar "$line":/root/newimages/
    ssh -np2222 -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$line" \
    'find /root/newimages/ -name "*.tar" -exec docker load -i {} \;'
   
done < servers.txt

In a normal run, it runs line by line, which takes a lot of time.
How can I run it in a less time, so that let's say 5 lines run at the same time instead of 1 line?
I mean, at the same time it should create an SSH connection to server1, server2, server3, server4 and server5 at the same time.
I don't know what words to google, if it's been asked before.

Wrap the body in parentheses to make a subshell, put an & after the close paren to run it in the background? Gets more complicated if you want to limit it to five at a time or whatever.

@ShadowRanger thanks, but I don't mean running in the background.

Can't rsync create the necessary target directory itself? That eliminates one of the ssh connections (bypassing the need to use a control socket that would let the two ssh connections share a single authenticated connection).

Why not run them in the background? That's effectively what you hre asking anyway. Add a wait at the end to prevent yourself from noticing.

I would use ansible.
If not using ansible, I would use GNU parallel or xargs. Something along:
#!/usr/bin/bash
func() {
    set -xeuo pipefail
    ssh -np2222 -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$1" \
      'mkdir -pv /root/newimages/'
    rsync -Ptrave 'ssh -p2222' /root/*.tar "$1":/root/newimages/
    ssh -np2222 -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$1" \
      'find /root/newimages/ -name "*.tar" -exec docker load -i {} \;'
}
export -f func
xargs -P0 -t -i bash -c 'func {}' <servers.txt

Maybe just:
#!/usr/bin/bash
func() {
    set -xeuo pipefail
    for i in /root/newimages/*.tar; do 
       ssh -np2222 -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
         "$1" docker load <"$i"
    done
}
export -f func
xargs -P0 -t -i bash -c 'func {}' <servers.txt

See man xargs

Thanks, ansible is a good solution. But I cannot find any documents regarding how many concurrent connections ansible has by default.

Ansible makes as many connections as many hosts there are. Dunno about default, there are different strategies. "forks" - https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#setting-the-number-of-forks . y default, Ansible runs each task on all hosts affected by a play before starting the next task on any host, using 5 fork the defualt is 5

You mean if I have 100 hosts, then it creates 100 connections at one time? I'm not sure about it but I think it doesn't do 100 connections.

@Saeed replace -P0 with -P5 to limit the number of concurrent/parallel operations to 5

#!/usr/bin/bash

# Maximum number of concurrent connections (adjust as needed)
MAX_CONNECTIONS=5

# Function to execute commands on a server in the background
run_on_server() {
  local server="$1"
  local command="$2"

  ssh -np2222 -o GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$server" &> /dev/null <<< "$command" &
}

# Read server list from file
servers=( $(cat servers.txt) )

# Track running processes for proper waiting
running_pids=()

# Loop through servers, spawning parallel connections
for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
  # Check if maximum connections reached
  while [[ ${#running_pids[@]} -ge $MAX_CONNECTIONS ]]; do
    # Wait for any finished background process
    wait -n

    # Remove the finished process ID from the array
    for pid in "${running_pids[@]}"; do
      if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
        unset running_pids[${!pid}]
        break
      fi
    done
  done

  # Create directory on remote server
  run_on_server "$server" 'mkdir -pv /root/newimages/'

  # Transfer archive files using parallel rsync
  rsync -Ptrave 'ssh -p2222' /root/*.tar "$server":/root/newimages/ &

  # Capture the process ID for tracking
  running_pids+=($!)
done

# Wait for all background processes to finish
wait

# Load Docker images on each server sequentially
for server in "${servers[@]}"; do
  run_on_server "$server" 'find /root/newimages/ -name "*.tar" -exec docker load -i {} \;'
done

echo "All tasks completed."

Explanation and Improvements:
Function for Parallel Commands: The run_on_server function encapsulates remote command execution with background processing (&), error silencing (&> /dev/null), and improved clarity.
Server List Handling: Uses an array servers to store server names from the file, enhancing readability and maintainability.
Connection Limiting: The MAX_CONNECTIONS variable controls concurrency, allowing you to adjust parallelism based on your network and server capabilities.
Process Tracking: running_pids array keeps track of background process IDs for proper waiting.
Concurrent rsync: The rsync command is run in the background (&) to achieve parallel file transfers.
Sequential Docker Loading: While parallel loading may be desirable in some cases, sequential loading is chosen here to avoid potential resource conflicts and ensure correct image loading order.
Robust Waiting: The wait -n loop handles foreground and background processes effectively. It terminates only when a child process finishes execution.
Error Handling: While full error handling is beyond the scope of this response, consider adding checks within the run_on_server function to handle potential failures and report them appropriately.
Flexibility: The script can be easily modified to accommodate different command sets, connection parameters, or handling of errors.
By incorporating these enhancements, this script provides a more robust and efficient way to execute tasks on multiple servers concurrently while addressing potential issues raised in the ratings.

Very bad: servers=( $(cat servers.txt) ). Replace by mapfile -t servers < servers.txt

running_pids+=($!) will add pid with a sequential index in the running_pids array. Then unset running_pids[${!pid}] will not unset the array entry corresponding to the PID. Use a sparse array and used pid as index like: running_pids[$!]=, then unset running_pids[$pid] will remove the sparse entry indexed by the PID.
